# Using Mathquill Interface in angular 6

Tags: angular, math, angular6, mathquill

I have used **Mathquill Interface** to create math editor for my website.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>math</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mathquill.com/lib/mathquill.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathquill/0.10.1/mathquill.css">
</head>

<style type="text/css">
    p {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
#math-field {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}
.btn{
    width: 50px;
}
</style>
<body><center>
<span id="math-field"></span><br><br><br>
<div id="keyboard">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onClick='input("\\theta")'>θ</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onClick='input("\\tau")'>τ</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onClick='input("\\chi")'> χ</button>

</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mathquill.com/lib/mathquill.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathquill/0.10.1/mathquill.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mathFieldSpan = document.getElementById('math-field');
    var MQ = MathQuill.getInterface(2);
    var mathField = MQ.MathField(mathFieldSpan, {
            spaceBehavesLikeTab: true,
            handlers: {
                edit: function() {
                mathField.focus();
                }
            }
        });
    const editor = new MathJaxEditorKeyboard('#myEditor')

    function input(str) {
      mathField.cmd(str);
      mathField.focus();

    }
</script>

</html>
```

This code works fine in *HTML* file.
I tried to use this code in angular application but it didn't work. 
please help to use **mathquill interface** in **Angular 6**

Comment: do you have some success with this?